# How to correctly backpropagate in neural networks?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I am trying to implement neural network without using any external libraries to understand it better, before implementation I made some calculations, but I am not $100\%$ certain they are correct.

**I am using notations:**

$b_i^{(L)}$ = bias in i-th neuron in L-th layer

$w_{xy}^{(L)}$ = weight in L-th layer comming from x-th neuron in previous layer to y-th neuron in current layer

$e_{xy}$ = expected output from last layer at y-th neuron from x-th training data

$a_{xy}^{(L)}$ = result of x-th training data at L-th layer in y-th neuron

$z_{xy}^{(L)}$ = result of x-th training data at L-th layer in y-th neuron before activation function. I am using sigmoid (*S(x)*), and therefore $a_{xy}^{(L)} = S(z_{xy}^{(L)})$;  $z_{xy}^{(L)} = b_y^{(L)} + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{|L-1|}w_{iy}^{(L)}a_{xi}^{(L-1)}$

$C_i$ = cost function of i-th training data ($=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{|L_{last}|}(a_{ij}^{(L)} - e_{ij})^2$ )

$C$ = total cost as average of all training data of size T (in current mini-batch). ($C = \frac1T*\sum\limits_{j=1}^{T}C_i$ )

$|L_i|$ = count of neurons in i-th layer

**These are my calculations I am trying to get gradient of for backpropagation:**

$\frac{\partial{C_i}}{\partial{b_x^{(L_{last})}}} = (2a_{ix}^{(L_{last})}-2e_{ix}) * S'(z_{ix}^{(L_{last})})$

$\frac{\partial{C_i}}{\partial{w_{xy}^{(L_{last})}}} = (2a_{iy}^{(L_{last})}-2e_{iy}) * S'(z_{iy}^{(L_{last})}) * a_{ix}^{(L_{last}-1)}$

$\frac{\partial{C_i}}{\partial{a_{ix}^{(L_{last}-1)}}} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{|L_{last}|}[(2a_{ij}^{(L_{last})}-2e_{ij}) * S'(z_{ij}^{(L_{last})}) * w_{xj}^{(L_{last})}]$

---

$\frac{\partial{C_i}}{\partial{b_x^{(L_{last}-1)}}} = \frac{\partial{C_i}}{\partial{a_{ix}^{(L_{last}-1)}}} * S'(z_{ix}^{(L_{last}-1)})$

$\frac{\partial{C_i}}{\partial{w_{xy}^{(L_{last}-1)}}} = \frac{\partial{C_i}}{\partial{a_{iy}^{(L_{last}-1)}}}* S'(z_{iy}^{(L_{last}-1)}) * a_{ix}^{(L_{last}-2)}$

$\frac{\partial{C_i}}{\partial{a_{ix}^{(L_{last}-2)}}} = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{|L_{last}-1|}[\frac{\partial{C_i}}{\partial{a_{ij}^{(L_{last}-1)}}} * S'(z_{ij}^{(L_{last}-1)}) * w_{xj}^{(L_{last}-1)}]$

---

*and so long...*

**Q1:** Are the calculations above correct?

Then I have all current values (weights and biases) let's say in some value vector $v$. Also, for each input I have a gradient vector $g_i$ corresponding to $v$ using calculations above. I suppose I create average of all $g_i$ to create final gradient vector $g$: $g = \frac1T * \sum\limits_{i=1}^{T}g_i$. (using MBGD)

To my understanding, what I have basically got is the direction of highest gain from point $v$ on the cost function $C$, so if I want to create altered value vector $v'$, I should use equation $v' = v - g$ to alter $v$ in opposite direction to minimize the difference from the expected output.

**Q2:** Is the gradient vector correctly used?

Also, I was wondering, **Q3:** does it make sense to alter my gradient a bit, for example to speed up the learning process, for example $v' = v - d*g$ where $d >= 1$, or generally use some modifying function $m$, such as $v' = v - m(g)$, or is raw gradient usually the best pick?

Comment: Please check out my edited equations, I have noticed some mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1: Are the calculations above correct?**

You're calculations seem correct, although I don't have time to meticulously make sure and understand your notation correctly, but it seems as though you correctly apply the chain rule and then when a parameter receives multiple gradients you sum them, which is the correct way to apply back prop.

**Q2: Is the gradient vector correctly used?**

As for how you're applying the gradient, you are partly correct. You do indeed subtract $g$ from $v$ to get $v'$ as you have done. This will decrease the cost function and make your model learn. However finding the average of the gradient is unnecessary, as by finding the average you are essentially just scaling the gradient by some factor, which you'll find is what a *learning rate* is. As such, it's much simpler to just have 1 single hyperparameter to control how much the gradient is scaled by, then to have the hyperparameter and also the gradient being averaged.

**Q3: does it make sense to alter my gradient a bit?**

Yes, it definitely does make sense to alter your gradient, but **never** by a factor of more than 1. Your model will not learn if you multiply the gradient by a factor greater than 1. This is because the model wont learn faster as you think it might, instead the gradient will just be wrong. An incorrect gradient will cause the error to exponentially diverge to infinity. As a general rule of thumb, a good learning rate (in your equations, a good value for $d$) would be something like 0.001 . Of course, you'll need to play around with it but that should ensure proper learning (I know it's a little surprising that the value is that low, but a low learning rate ensures your model rarely overshoots local minima).

Comment: So it's better to apply gradient like this: $g = ~0.001 g_i$? In my question (which I forgot to mention) I was trying to use Mini-batch gradient descent method which I have read should be optimal (compared to GD or SGD) - that's where the average comes from. Can you explain a bit further why it's unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, it's better to scale the final gradient vector by some small value. The reason averaging isn't necessary is because you are simply scaling the gradient by 1/(batch size), and then after that you are also scaling by the learning rate. It's easier to just have both of these scaling steps be 1 step of just 1 hyper parameter. It's not that your model wont learn - it just makes it a bit simpler and easier to know how the gradient will be affected by your learning rate.